# Check the content start with the one letter and followed by any one with another content using java script regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to the javascript regular expressions

I need to test the content startting the one letter and followed by any one with another string like below

```
var searchValue=$(this).val();
var divText=$("#someId").text();
if(^searchValue.test(divText)) {
    alert("Match some thing here");
    //do whatever you want
}
```

Can any one help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note: `java` is not `javascript`

Comment: you don't need a regex, something as simple as this will work: `searchValue.indexOf(divText) === 0`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: Thanks  zamnuts,                                                           Actually What I am trying to do is I have one string having some data like String1= "Electrical Engineering"  and I have one more string like String2= "Ele"   Now I need to compare like is there any string data is contains starting with string 2 means "Ele"